# How to display mdframed title in header?

Tags: header-footer, mdframed

I have a series of `mdframed` frames in the document. Some frames are few pages long, and some pages have two frames within.

How can I display the `frametitle` of the corresponding page in the header as we display `section`s in the header.

```
\begin{mdframed}[style=example,frametitle=Some Title]
....
\end{mdframed}
\begin{mdframed}[style=example,frametitle=Some Title]
.....
\end{mdframed}
```

Comment: are you using `fancyhdr`?

Comment: @cmhughes yes, I have it too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package `mdframed` stores the frame title in the command `\mdf@frametitle`. To bring this title to the header I used the internal command `\@mkboth`. This command is used inside the definitions of headings. Based on the token `@` you have to use `makeatletter`/`makeatother`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\mdfdefinestyle{example}{settings={\@mkboth{\mdf@frametitle}{\mdf@frametitle}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=example,frametitle=Some Title 1]
\lipsum
\end{mdframed}
\begin{mdframed}[style=example,frametitle=Some Title 2]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}

\begin{mdframed}[style=example,frametitle=Some Title 3]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\begin{mdframed}[style=example,frametitle=Some Title 4]
\lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]