# header conflict with mdframed

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, mdframed

```
\documentclass{book}    
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{my header} }

\tableofcontents
\part{part one}
\Blinddocument 
\part{part two}
\Blinddocument 

\chapter{THE CHAPTER}

\mdfdefinestyle{stylesec}{backgroundcolor=gray!10,linecolor=gray!50,roundcorner=3pt}
\begin{mdframed}[style=stylesec]
\section{section 1}
\smallskip
\end{mdframed}
\Blindtext 

\begin{mdframed}[style=stylesec]
\section{section 2}
\smallskip
\end{mdframed}
\Blindtext 

\begin{mdframed}[style=stylesec]
\section{section 3}
\smallskip
\end{mdframed}
\Blindtext 

\begin{mdframed}[style=stylesec]
\section{section 4}
\smallskip
\end{mdframed}
\Blindtext 

\end{document}
```

As my title said when I use mdframed from **THE CHAPTER**, for some reason **my header** disappears. Note that I tried the package titlesec with the same result.

Comment: I suppose that by ‘header’, you mean the section title?

Comment: no, I mean the text at the top left of the odd pages.

Comment: Compiling your code, the section titles are not inserted in a framed box on my system. This being said, you probably should do that with `titlesec`.

Comment: With this code, it works with titlesec. But this is minimal code to figure out the issue and solve it if it is possible. The fact is in my book titlesec does not work (probably a conflict with some other packages), so I have to solve it with mdframed, or else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it thanks to this post
[How to display mdframed title in header?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52608/how-to-display-mdframed-title-in-header?rq=1)

My solution is:

```
 \makeatletter 
 \mdfdefinestyle{stylesec}{settings={\@mkboth{THE CHAPTER}{my header}},backgroundcolor=gray!10,linecolor=gray!50,roundcorner=3pt}
 \makeatother
```